# Issue getting Doxygen to document an enum in C

Tags: documentation, enums, doxygen

I have a rather odd problem with Doxygen (1.6.1 on Mac OS X Snow Leopard) in that it does not seem to document my enums no matter what I do. I am programming in C and have followed the instructions in the manual. Here is my code:

```
/**
 * \enum dccp_pkt_type 
 * \brief specifies the available DCCP packet types
 */

enum dccp_pkt_type
{
    DCCP_REQUEST    = 0,    /**< DCCP Request Packet */
    DCCP_RESPONSE,          /**< DCCP Response Packet */
    DCCP_DATA,              /**< DCCP Data Packet */
    DCCP_ACK,               /**< DCCP Ack Packet */
    DCCP_DATAACK,           /**< DCCP Data Ack Packet */
    DCCP_CLOSEREQ,          /**< DCCP Close Request Packet */
    DCCP_CLOSE,             /**< DCCP Close Packet */
    DCCP_RESET,             /**< DCCP Reset Packet */
    DCCP_SYNC,              /**< DCCP Sync Packet */
    DCCP_SYNCACK,           /**< DCCP Sync Ack Packet */
    DCCP_RESERVED,          /**< DCCP Reserved Packet Type - Receivers MUST
                         ignore any packets with this type */
};
```

It should according to the doxygen manual produce properly documentated output but instead it produces nothing. I am most likely missing something simple, if anyone could point me in the right direction I would be grateful.

Comment: General comment not addressing the question: Your [Doxygen] comments for individual enum values (perhaps with the exception of 
 the "ignore" note for DCCP_RESERVED) do not add anything useful, just clutter the view.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

From the [Doxygen manual](http://www.doxygen.nl//manual/docblocks.html):

> Let’s repeat that, because it is often
>   overlooked: to document global objects
>   (functions, typedefs, enum, macros,
>   etc), you must document the file in
>   which they are defined. In other
>   words, there must at least be a
>
> `/*! \file */` or a
>
> `/** @file */` line in this file.

Answer (score 11):

My experience is the same using `EXTRACT_ALL=NO` and `SHOW_INCLUDE_FILES=NO` with doxygen 1.8.9.1 - global enum types were not listed nor linked even though `/*! \file */` is present and the global `enum` is referenced by a documented compound structure.

To work around this, I ended up defining an Enumerations group:

`/*! 
    \defgroup Enumerations
        Public enumeration types
*/`

and for the enum types I used `\ingroup Enumerations` to include the enums in the new group.  Doxygen then was able to autolink from the compound structures to the enum types.

Comment: I'm finding this too in version 1.8.11.

Answer (score 4):

If memory serves correctly, enum documentation doesn't show up unless the file is also documented.  Try adding a @file section.