# Doxygen treats main.c differently from other files

Tags: c, doxygen

The header comments in my main.c are not being processed by doxygen, however if I rename the file from main.c to for example mainn.c it works very well.

Why is main.c treated differently from an other file name?
How do I make Doxygen manage main.c as other .c files?

Or alternatively, what is the best practice here? My purpose in Main.c is to put a short (maybe not so short) product description and use cases in the header documentation.

The header file starts as such:

```
/**********************************************************//**
* @file    main.c
* @author  Somebody
* @brief   Main function and support functions.
* @details
```

Then continues with application level things I want to document.
Doxygen configuration is the default as it is installed, except for a few items, such as optimised for C, include call charts etc...

Thanks..

Comment: Well, _how_ does Doxygen treat `main.c`? If you want to add a short description, add `\file main.c` to the file. Also, it depends on your Doxygen configuration.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Doxygen not documenting main function in main.cpp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12041274/doxygen-not-documenting-main-function-in-main-cpp)

Answer (score 0):

Kinda hard to tell without seeing how you've tried to document it... But make sure you have a line in the main.c file that reads

```
/*! file */
```

or

```
/** @file */
```

(Doxygen doesn't document global objects by default)

Answer (score 0):

After mucking around a bit here is the solution. (As proposed by MPI_What.

As mentioned in my question

```
/**********************************************************//**
 * @file    main.c
 * @author  Somebody
 * @brief   Main function and support functions.
 * @details
```

Works for all files except main.c (Of course the line @file main.c is different for the other files. However the following works well for main.c also:

```
/**********************************************************//**
 * @file    
 * @author  Somebody
 * @brief   Main function and support functions.
 * @details
```

Why it works is a mystery, but it does. 
Thanks, Adrian