# Documenting C++ aliases in Doxygen

Tags: c++, alias, doxygen, typedef, using

With the appropriate comment in front of it, Doxygen generates entries for `class`, `struct` and `namespace` declarations but not occurrences of `typedef` or `using`.

In this example

```
/// here is my typedef
typedef int MyTypedef;

/// here is my namespace
namespace MyNamespace 
{
  /// here is my other typedef
  typedef int MyOtherTypedef;
}
```

I get an entry in the documentation for `MyNamespace` and even `MyOtherTypedef` but there is nothing for `MyTypedef`. Why not?

Answer (score 4):

The answer is the same as the answers to why entries for [functions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12041646/671509) and [preprocessor definitions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2356722/671509) are not automatically generated.

Doxygen considers aliases, variables, functions and macros (but not classes or namespaces) to be 'objects'. And all 'objects' are documented *iff* their containing file, class or namespace is also documented.

For `MyTypedef` to feature in your documentation, add:

```
/// \file
/// here is my file
```

anywhere in the global scope of your file.